# Powershell foreach SQL Server query randomly collates DataSet

Tags: sql, powershell, dataset, powershell-5.0

I needed to make a simple housekeeping script checking 14 SQL Server's tables.
I ended up using [Adam's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1724064/adam) script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423541/how-do-you-run-a-sql-server-query-from-powershell) question.

However when run, it skips posting results for a random amount of servers, and then dumps their queries in one table, then does any remaining servers individually. What have I done wrong? (Since I can't comment on Adam's answer)

I wouldn't mind collating all the data in a table and dump at the end, but then with columns for server name and result, if that is easier to accomplish.

This is my script, example output below;

```
$year = Get-Date -Format yyyy
$servers = gc 'ServerList.txt'

foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
    try
    {
        $ServerName = "$server"
        $DatabaseName = "DatabaseName"
        $Query = "select count(*) from Alarm_Activations where Activation_Date not like '%$year%'"
        #$ds = $null -Tried adding this to fix the issue

        #Timeout parameters
        $QueryTimeout = 120
        $ConnectionTimeout = 30

        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "  Checking $server "

        #Action of connecting to the Database and executing the query and returning results if there were any.
        $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
        $ConnectionString = "Data Source=$server\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Connect Timeout=30; Integrated security=true;"
        $conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString

        $conn.Open()

        $cmd = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
        $cmd.CommandTimeout = $QueryTimeout

        $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
        $da = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
        [void]$da.fill($ds)
        $conn.Close()

        Write-Host "Number of activations older than $year :"
        $ds.Tables
    } 
    catch 
    {
        Write-Error "Something went wrong. Seems you have to do it manually!"
        return
    }
}
```

Example output

The point of dumping the table seems random, but is usually past half the servers.

Earliest I've seen is Server-5, latest; Server-14;

```
& CheckAlarmActivation.ps1


  Checking Server-1
Number of activations older than 2019 :



  Checking Server-2
Number of activations older than 2019 :


  Checking Server-3
Number of activations older than 2019 :


  Checking Server-4
Number of activations older than 2019 :


  Checking Server-5
Number of activations older than 2019 :


  Checking Server-6
Number of activations older than 2019 :


  Checking Server-7
Number of activations older than 2019 :


  Checking Server-8
Number of activations older than 2019 :


  Checking Server-9
Number of activations older than 2019 :


  Checking Server-10
Number of activations older than 2019 :
Column1
-------
      0
      0
      0
   3318
   1069
   4375
      8
   9357
     74
   1735


  Checking Server-11
Number of activations older than 2019 :
   7917


  Checking Server-12
Number of activations older than 2019 :
   3583


  Checking Server-13
Number of activations older than 2019 :
   5622


  Checking Server-14
Number of activations older than 2019 :
   4166
```

Comment: I would start with replacing `Write-Host` with `Write-Output`. Interaction with the host isn't synchronous as far as I know.

Comment: Unrelated tip: Put the conn.Close in a `finally` block, like so: `finally { $conn.Close() }` Reason?  PowerShell doesnt support using statement to ensure signaling to the connection pool to dispose of connection.

Comment: I moved all the write-hosts down to just above $ds.Tables, and made a finally block for $conn.Close. The script now performs as expected, writing one result per server, and then doing the next. However the first server has it's output as a table, with Column1 as the header, and one row with the result. The rest just print the result. I assume this is due to my bad handling of the DataSet? I'll have a look at Brandon McLure's suggestion as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like AdminOfThings commented, use `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host`. Because you are using the `Write-Host` stream and just outputting a variable (which goes to the output stream)(`$ds.Tables`) you are not seeing both streams on the console at the same time.

In addition to using `Write-Output`, I would approach the problem by storing the results of your DB calls (and any results you want to return from them) as PSObjects that you put into a collection, and then after you iterate through all your severs you can format the output (to console, generate a csv/html report, etc) all in one go. The benefit to this approach is that your script will not fail if one of the servers is down.

**Edit** I updated the catch block to grab the exception the right way. I also updated where you get the value from the data set to expand out so you do not have a data row object. You can use more advanced `Select-Object` logic if you have multiple columns, or you want to create calculated properties based on some of your columns. [SO post with more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744802/fastest-way-to-convert-process-datatable-to-custom-psobject). In your case, you only want to get the count of records back.

```
$serverResults = @()
$servers = "srv1","srv2"

foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
  # Create an instance of a custom object that will hold the results of your query. Add properties as needed, they can be other complex objects, or simple types. 
   $serverResultInstance = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   ServerName = $server
   DatabaseName = $DatabaseName 
   Tables = $null
   Exception = $null
   }
 try{
    #Connect to DB like you do (Don't use Write-Host)
    #Add your dataset for this instance 
    $ServerName = "$server"
        $DatabaseName = "dbName"
        $Query = "select count(*) from sys.columns"
        #$ds = $null -Tried adding this to fix the issue

        #Timeout parameters
        $QueryTimeout = 120
        $ConnectionTimeout = 30

        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Checking $server"

        #Action of connecting to the Database and executing the query and returning results if there were any.
        $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
        $ConnectionString = "Data Source=$server;Initial Catalog=$DatabaseName;Connect Timeout=$ConnectionTimeout; Integrated security=true;"
        $conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString

        $conn.Open()

        $cmd = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
        $cmd.CommandTimeout = $QueryTimeout

        $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
        $da = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
        [void]$da.fill($ds)

        # Instead of keeping the whole table/row object, expand out the column you want. If you have multiple columns or tables in your dataset you would need to change these values. 
    $serverResultInstance.Tables = $ds.Tables[0] | select -ExpandProperty Column1
 }
 catch{
    #This should have been $_.Exception
    $serverResultInstance.Exception = $_.Exception
 }
 finally{
    $conn.Close()
    $serverResults  += $serverResultInstance
 }
}
foreach($result in $serverResultInstance){
# Format your output here. Make a csv, send an email, etc. Or just:
 Write-Output "Number of activations older than $year :"
 Write-Output $result.Tables

}
```

Comment: Ok, so first I got not object not found for the `catch{ serverResultInstance.Exception = $_  }`. Changed it to `catch { $serverResultInstance.Exceptions = $_  }` and now it says the Exceptions property can't be found for object, even though we clearly made it earlier, spelling checked ofc. Also tried `catch { $serverResultInstance.Exception = $_ }` but same problem.

Comment: Commenting out the catch I'm able to proceed, however I'm struggling to output the data from the system.data object, using `write-output $serverResults | format-table ServerName, Alarm_Activations` This provides a table with server name, and {System.Data.DataRow}

Comment: @Hargaut, I fixed the bug in the catch, and added code to show how to get the value itself from the data table (instead of a DataRow). Also updated my comment syntax fromC# to Powershell :-) Let me know if that gives you any issues/if formatting the datarow like that will work for your case.